# How can I put an image on a slides title page?

Tags: graphics

How can I put an image (a jpg file) on the title page in the slides documentclass? I am NOT using Beamer.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! It does not really help to know what you don’t use. I guess that you know about the package `graphicx` and its macro `\includegraphics{}`. Please put a minimal working example here, so that others know what you want to achieve.

Comment: I must admit that I am a bit baffled about what is unclear about my question. Do you know what the "slides" documentclass is? Do you know what the title page is of such a class? Do you know what it means to put an image on that title page? What is it that is unclear about my question? I'm curious to know, but I solved the problem anyway, so it doesn't really matter anyway. You are welcome to just delete the question if that is simpler. Thanks.

Comment: There are a lot of packages for slides. So, it was not clear to me that you use the `slides` document class. Further, I wondered where exactly you wanted to put this picture on your title page, because this could imply a different approach. This is why I asked you to provide a small code snippet. In general, providing a MWE is the best thing to do on this side, because it helps others to come up with a simple solution that best fits the relevant set up.

Answer (score 1):

After some experimenting, I found that I could use \includegraphics to put the image (a logo) right inside the \title or \author. With appropriate newlines, I got it to look the way I want it, centered horizontally on the page and (approximately) vertically between the title and author.

The reason I specified that I am not using Beamer is because when I did my initial search I found that all the returned results pertained to Beamer. I am just using the slides document class to automate the packaging of a set of plots (one per page) into a single pdf file. Beamer is overkill for my purposes here.